How do I implement a MessageSourceMutator that dynamically sets the remote directory based on the date format yyyymmdd and can go thru a date range?
Im using spring sftp integration (Inbound) to read files from directories in a base SFTP directory, /foo/maindir. The sub directories are in the format: yyyymmdd and contain the files I need to download and process. How do I traverse these directories using MessageSourceMutator to dynamically set the remote directory based on the current date. I would also appreciate sample code to traverse directories between dates.
I will appreciate any assistance.
I have seen mention of the MessageSourceMutator Advice as the only option to achieve but can't seem to find any sample to better understand how to do this.
